# print result with Pthread (main) C

Tags: c, pthreads

I'm trying to make a simple program in C that will use main thread to print an result, but when I check thread ID when I create thread and when I print result its 2 different IDs. Here is my code:
Cx

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

void *Utskrift(void *simpleInt)
{
  int simple;

simple = (int)simpleInt;
/*Printing my result and thread id*/
printf(";Hello From Thread ! I got fed with
an int %d! AND it is THREAD    ::%d\n",simple,pthread_self());

 }


 main(){

pthread_t thread_id;
int test=2;
/*Using main thread to print test from method Utskrift*/
pthread_create (&thread_id, NULL,&Utskrift,(void *) test);
/*Taking look at my thread id*/
printf(" (pthread id %d) has started\n", pthread_self());
pthread_join(thread_id,NULL);


}
```

I'm new to Thread Programming and C as well. So I may have misunderstood `pthread_create (&thread_id, NULL,&Utskrift,(void *) test);`. Does it use my main thread to call method `Utskrift` and print the result, or does it create a new thread "child" to my main thread and then the child prints the result? If so, can you please explain for me how to use the main thread to print my "test".

Output:

```
(pthread id -1215916352) has started ;Hello From Thread ! I got fed with an int 2! AND it is THREAD ::-1215919248
```

Comment: Can you post your output?

Comment: (pthread id -1215916352) has started
;Hello From Thread ! I got fed with an int 2! AND it is THREAD ::-1215919248

Comment: Please format your code correctly when posting here. Also your `(void*)test` thing is cruft. At your state of understanding you should never use casts, and later when you are more firm on C, the least possible. If you copied such a thing from somewhere, maybe change your source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pthread_create` function([spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_create.html)) creates a new thread which will execute the function you pass to it (in this case `Utskrift`).  The value value passed in `pthread_create`'s last parameter is passed to the function.

If you simply wanted to call the `Utskrift` function in your main thread, you could do it the normal way:

```
Utskrift((void *)test));
```

If you want to pass data back from your completed thread to another thread, you can use `pthread_join` which will return either the value returned by your thread's start routine, or the value that thread passes to `pthread_exit`:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void *checker(void *arg) {
    int number = (int) arg;

    if (0 == number)
        return "number was zero";
    else
        return "number was not zero";
}

int main(void) {
    int test = 0;
    pthread_t thread_id;
    char *s;

    pthread_create (&thread_id, NULL, checker,(void *) test);
    pthread_join(thread_id, &s);
    printf("%s\n", s);

    test = 1;

    pthread_create (&thread_id, NULL, checker,(void *) test);
    pthread_join(thread_id, &s);
    printf("%s\n", s);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Samuel this was very helpful for me. I have i tried this code and even modified it a bit. And now i got understanding of how this actually workers. My next question is if it possible to pass back an array by pthread_join? I could not fix it and only got first element returned and last elements was returned as "98232179" numbers. I think it because of retrun *Myarray only returns value of first element. can u give some example on how to   pass and array by pthread_join

Comment: @MaxMansour, not exactly.  Arrays are a little bit complicated in C.  This seems to be a good article on ways to accomplish what you want: http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx5.html

Comment: Also, if this answer solved your problem please select the "accept" checkmark so that I can receive points for it and others will know the question has been answered acceptably.

Answer (score 1):

The `main()` is also a thread. So when you create a thread you basically fork from `main()` and process something else in the new thread. `pthread_join()` will wait till you new thread exits and then will continue with the main thread. Hope that makes some sense.

Answer (score 0):

This line in `main`:

```
printf(" (pthread id %d) has started\n", pthread_self());
```

is printing the pthread id of the main thread, not the one you previously created. What id you get in the thread should be the same as the one stored in `thread_id`. You probably meant to write:

```
printf(" (pthread id %d) has started\n", thread_id);
```

---

Side note: `pthread_t` is often larger than just an int. I recommend printing it like this:

```
printf("... %lu ...", ..., (unsigned long)thread_id, ...);
```

Comment: Aha so as i uderstod it right if i want to print somthing by a main thread than i dont even need anotherer void method (like Utskrift) i can simply just do printf from main since  main is olso a thread?

Comment: @MaxMansour, Yes, when your program starts, it is already a thread. You may want more threads to compute something in parallel, or do different things in parallel. Indeed, if all you want to do is `printf`, you don't need another thread. I would say again, if you don't want things to run in parallel, you don't need threads.